# The Trivial Centre of Group $G/Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $G = G'$, where $G'= [G,G]$ is the Derived Subgroup of $G$. Prove that the centre o group $G/Z(G)$ is trivial, that is, prove that $Z\left(G/Z(G) \right) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $xZ(G)\in Z(G/Z(G))$ then $$xgZ(G)=gxZ(G)$$ for all $g\in G$ which means
$$[x,g]Z(G)=Z(G)$$ i.e $[x,g]\in Z(G)$.

So we have, $[x,G]\in Z(G)\implies [x,G,G]=e$  by similar reasoning $[G,x,G]=e$ by three subgroup lemma $[G,G,x]=[G,x]=e\implies x\in Z(G)\implies xZ(G)=Z(G)$ which is the trivial element of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: @AgenorAndrade: You are welcome.